# bash terminal : command not found & zsh terminal : not found

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, macos

Can someone explain me and help me
how can I fix it ?

this is what I see bash termnial :

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: eva: command not found
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: Source: command not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MacBook-Pro-de-ta:~ ta$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for ta.
Password for ta: 
chsh: no changes made
MacBook-Pro-de-ta:~ ta$
```

what i see on zsh terminal :

```
/Users/ta/.zshrc:3: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4@global/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/ta/.rvm/bin not found
```

more details :

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % bash --version 
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % /Users/ta/.bash_profile
zsh: permission denied: /Users/ta/.bash_profile
```

```
ta@MacBook-Pro-de-ta ~ % /Users/ta/.zsh_profile
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/ta/.zsh_profile
```

```
source ~/.bash_profile
/Users/ta/.bash_profile:6: command not found: rbenv
/Users/ta/.bash_profile:6: command not found: eva
/Users/ta/.bash_profile:7: command not found: rbenv
/Users/ta/.bash_profile:11: command not found: Source
```

Comment: You do not execure .*_profile files, they are read by the relevent shell. If you need them, then read them with `source ~/.bash_profile` etc. The `rbenv` seems to be from Ruby. You cannot mix and match shell commands.

Comment: Thanks I add the "source ~/.bash_profile".
can you explain me how to fix this ?

Comment: Fic what? All we have is some random errors.

Comment: We can see that line 3 of your .zshrc has a syntax error, at least.  I suspect that there are a lot of them in your .bash_profile too.

Comment: @Ta THR Check your .bash_profile and .zshrc for errors. They should be shell scripts in the corresponding shell, not Ruby scripts. https://www.shellcheck.net could help to a point.

Comment: @Vilinkameni thank you !!!